# Encrypt Oracle communication in .Net

Tags: .net, oracle, encryption

I developped a .NET programm that connects to Oracle database through an Oracle Client installed on my PC.

I found with Wireshark that the Oracle authentication is encrypted (no plaintext password in the communication between the Oracle client and the server).

But after that, all the communication between the client and the database are not encrypted !

Is there any option on the .Net code to force the encryption of all flows ?

Here is my connection to the DB :

`OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
 cmd.Connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString)
 cmd.Connection.Open();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to encrypt the SQLNet itself. You can either configure this with .Net driver options or with sqlnet.ora.

A short and good description can be found here http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Network_Encryption

Requirement: Oracle Enterprise Edition